# The time format is not respected in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have the following problem I am working with Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms Version = 10.0.0.0 in visual studio 2010 .NET 4 I am doing an attendance report

[image: report design image]

In the Value section of the field I have the following * CDate (Fields! Time1.Value) .ToString ("hh: mm tt") * I want the time to be converted to am / pm format on a windows 10 machine yes It works but when passing it to the server where the report that is a windows 2012 R2 Standard will be hosted, it does not show me that format, I attach an image of how it looks on the server

[image: report on server]

I also tried converting it to the format like this: **Convert.ToDateTime (Fields! Time1.Value) .ToString ("hh: mm: ss tt")**
But it does not work

I checked the server time format and it is correct.
[image: registry settings]

I am using IIS

[image: cultural reference]

Is there something else I need to configure or why is the format not up to me?

Upgrade:

[image upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzL9q.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykEbW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding new System.Globalization.CultureInfo ("en-US")

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmHg4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `CultureInfo`.

```
date1 = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 18, 9, 1);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 06:09:01 PM
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100)

Comment: Hello @wazz I already tried what you told me but I get the error that I put :(